# Running Total/count with Reset

Tags: sql, reset, running-count

I currently need to make a query that creates a running total for a user table depending on a specific status and resets once their status changes. I've done the usual running total script but my problem lies on that I'm unsure how to make the count start from 1 again once they go back to that specific status.
This is the table that I currently have right now:

| User | Status | Date | Status_desc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User 1 | Working | 03-01-2023 | 1 |
| User 1 | Working | 02-01-2023 | 1 |
| User 1 | Absent | 01-01-2023 | 0 |
| User 1 | Working | 12-01-2022 | 1 |
| User 1 | Working | 11-01-2022 | 1 |
| User 1 | Working | 11-01-2022 | 1 |
| User 2 | Working | 03-01-2023 | 1 |
| User 2 | Absent | 02-01-2023 | 0 |
| User 2 | Absent | 01-01-2023 | 0 |
| User 2 | Working | 12-01-2022 | 1 |
| User 2 | Working | 11-01-2022 | 1 |
| User 2 | Working | 11-01-2022 | 1 |

This are the results that I'm trying to get for the running total:

| User | Status | Date | Status_desc | Running_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User 1 | Working | 03-01-2023 | 1 | 2 |
| User 1 | Working | 02-01-2023 | 1 | 1 |
| User 1 | Absent | 01-01-2023 | 0 | 0 |
| User 1 | Working | 12-01-2022 | 1 | 3 |
| User 1 | Working | 11-01-2022 | 1 | 2 |
| User 1 | Working | 11-01-2022 | 1 | 1 |
| User 2 | Working | 03-01-2023 | 1 | 1 |
| User 2 | Absent | 02-01-2023 | 0 | 0 |
| User 2 | Absent | 01-01-2023 | 0 | 0 |
| User 2 | Working | 12-01-2022 | 1 | 3 |
| User 2 | Working | 11-01-2022 | 1 | 2 |
| User 2 | Working | 11-01-2022 | 1 | 1 |

I've tried the normal running total window function and it didn't work since my partition was the status. Is there any workaround for this?

```
select *
    , sum(t0.working_flag)
    OVER (PARTITION BY (t0.status_desc)
         ORDER BY t0.date asc)
from (select *
    , case when status_desc = 'working' then '1'
    else 0
    end as working_flag
from table) t0
order by date desc
```

Comment: Please do take a moment to look at the preview when posting; you would have been able to spot that your tables did not render and could fix it prior to posting.

Comment: I've removed the conflicting RDBMS tags here. Please [edit] your question to re tag the one you are *really" using and only that youm adding your attemp(s) to the question and an explanation of why they aren't working would also be beneficial.

Comment: Are working and absent the only status options?

Answer (score 0):

```
with data as (
    select *.
        count(case when Status = 'Absent' then 1 end) over (partition by User order by Date) as grp
    from T
)
select *,
    count(case when Status <> 'Absent' then 1 end) over (partition by User, grp order by Date) as RunningTotal
from data
order by User, Date desc;
```